# Graph Theory: Vertex and Edge Relationships in Non-connected Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

In my University for a project they gave us this question:

We denote by  the number of vertices and by  the number of edges of a graph. Let  be a graph with  ≥ 5 and  ≥ 3 − 5. Let  be a set of vertices of  with || = 2, such that the graph that results after the removal of  from  (i.e., the  − ) is non-connected. In the graph  − , we denote by 1 the set of vertices of a connected component and we denote by 2 the set of vertices from all the other connected components. We consider the graphs 1 = [ ∪ 1] and 2 = [ ∪ 2] with 1, 1, and 2, 2 the number of vertices and edges of 1 and 2, respectively. Show that if every vertex of  has a degree of at least 4, then:
(a) 5 ≤ 1 < , 5 ≤ 2 <  and
(b) 1 ≥ 31 − 5 or 2 ≥ 32 − 5

So far to visualize the question I took the case that we have 5 vertexes, from the question information we come to the conclusion that we have at least 10 edges. But this graph is complete so how we can remove two vertexes and have a non-connected graph?

I would appreciate any help, thank you in advance!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) instead of Unicode to type all your formulae.

Comment: To test examples, you need to either allow multi-edges or to take a bigger graph.